# how to do replacement of mulile string with multiple values in regex python

Tags: python, regex, jupyter-notebook

Given the following string:

```
"""
All I want is a proper cup of coffee
Made in a proper copper coffee pot
I may be off my dot
But I want a cup of coffee
From a proper coffee pot
Tin coffee pots and iron coffee pots
They’re no use to me
If I can’t have a proper cup of coffee
In a proper copper coffee pot
I’ll have a cup of tea.
"""
```

Using regular expressions, i need to write a function that highlight the words “coffee”,“pot” or “pots”
if they appear at the end of a line
so the patter i tried is
`coffee$|pot$|pots$` ( since $ is used for endwith)

if i do in regex101 it s highlighting all the required words

hoewever output in jupyter notebook  is

```
'All I want is a proper cup of coffee\nMade in a proper copper coffee pot\nI may be off my dot\nBut I want a cup of coffee\nFrom a proper coffee pot\nTin coffee pots and iron coffee pots\nThey’re no use to me\nIf I can’t have a proper cup of coffee\nIn a proper copper coffee pot\nI’ll have a cup of tea'
```

i tried with coffee$  coffee$\n  coffee\n$ nothing works here. if i use `.replace("\n", " ")` it its taking as whole string. how to handle \n in jupyter notebook

[image]
tried in regex101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "highlight", but here's an example of a RegEx that matches all instances "coffee", "pot", and "pots" at the end of a line:

```
import re

string = """
All I want is a proper cup of coffee
Made in a proper copper coffee pot
I may be off my dot
But I want a cup of coffee
From a proper coffee pot
Tin coffee pots and iron coffee pots
They’re no use to me
If I can’t have a proper cup of coffee
In a proper copper coffee pot
I’ll have a cup of tea.
"""

pattern = re.compile(r'(coffee|pots?)(?:\n)')
print(re.findall(pattern, string))
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/Nnb6EU/1) for a breakdown of the RegEx pattern used.

Comment: just to make coffee pot and pots which are at the end of line to be replaced with {coffee}, {pot},{pots}